# How to ask the user via Input a Function? - Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: functions, user-interface, input

I need to ask the user the function to make some procedures. For example, instead of having at the code

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[1 + x];
```

and then

```
f[5]
```

I need to do something like this:

```
userFunction = Input["Type your function"]
f[x_] := userFunction;
```

Of course the user should type a valid function, like `Sqrt[x]`, but it´s not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 userFunction = Input["Type your function"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 f[x_] := Evaluate@userFunction;
 f[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great, it works! Edit, I've tried with other results and the decimals are the same. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works the same for me.   Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a620X.png)   Are you typing `Log2[x]`  and adding "" around it? That will make it string. Just type `Log2[x]` in the input box, without double quotes.

Comment: Already checked and solved the problem, it was a factor method, at decimals it was the same. Again, thanks a lot!